# RxJS handling promise rejection

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

I have a DB query call e.g. `getUserByIdOrThrow(id: number): User`;
How can I properly handle possible promise rejection after `getUserByIdOrThrow` call?
In case of an error, I need to ignore it completely, but if promise resolved successfully, I need to call another async function.

Example flow:

```
         DBCallAsync
       /            \
    resolved       rejected
     /                \
 another call       do nothing
```

That how I tried to approach this problem (not working as I expected):

```js
from(this.dbService.getUserByIdOrThrow(100)).pipe(
  tap(({ phone }) => {
    from(this.userService.sendMessage(phone, "hello")).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        // doesnt catches
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    )
  }),
catchError((err) => {
  // doesnt catches
  return EMPTY;
}));
```

How can I implement this in the right way?

Comment: Why do you want to use rxjs for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both functions return Promise I wouldn't recommend of using an Observable, you would be much better handling it in a Promise way:

```js
try {
  const { phone } = await this.dbService.getUserByIdOrThrow(100);
  await this.userService.sendMessage(phone, "hello"))
} catch (error) {

}
```

Or using RXJS style if you are insist on using it (`switchMap` operator is used for returning and flattaning an inner obsevable, in addition there's no need to use `from` inside `switchMap` since it can handle Promises)

```js
from(this.dbService.getUserByIdOrThrow(100))
  .pipe(
    switchMap(({ phone }) => this.userService.sendMessage(phone, "hello")),
    catchError((err) => EMPTY)
   );
```